# Possible orderings with constraints

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, sorting, constraint-satisfaction

Given variables **{A, B, ,,,,,Z}**
We want to sort these varibles according to given constraints.

The constrains are in below format:

***X Y Z***

- meaning the third variable (**Z**) is not in the range between first and second variables (**X, Y)**
- **X > Y** or **X > Y**, we don't know. and **Z** can be greater than both **X** and **Y** or smaller than both which we don't know either
- for example **XYZ**, **ZXY**, **YXZ**, **ZYX** are all valid ordering given this constraint
- We are given at least 200 of such constraints such as:
  **A B C

  E B K

  X Y Z**
  ....

We want to generate possible orderings of  **{A, B, ,,,,,Z}** as many as possible
Also the algorithm has to be faster than **O(N!)** (N is the number of variables)
I'm not sure how can I approach this problem, we don't have to generate all possible ordering but the more the better.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Where have you encounter this task?

Comment: Can you credit the source where you encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly answer your question, but can help. The problem you are looking at is complement to the Betweenness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness) problem. In your problem, for the constraint $X,Y,Z$ you do not want to generate sequences where-:
1. no sub-sequence beginning with X and ending with Y contains Z somewhere in between or 
2. sub-sequence beginning with Y and ending with X contains Z somewhere in between.
For the betweenness problem wit variables $X, Y, Z$ and constraint $X, Z, Y$ means $X, Z, Y$ and $Y, Z, X$ are the only valid solutions. So, one can look at efficient solution techniques for the betweenness problem and simply remove all those solutions to the betweenness problem from the $N!$ possible orderings.